# is there any lightweight javascript framework for managing html5 history

Tags: angularjs, html

i tried angularjs which is very powerful and fat. it's size is more than 100k. is there any lightweight js framework only for managing html5 webpage history in a mvc project?

How about Jquery MVC project? have you any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage: 5-10MB

Quoting Google search:

> Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored
>   locally, without affecting website performance. Unlike cookies, the
>   storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never
>   transferred to the server.

Quoting wikipedia

> Web storage can be viewed simplistically as an improvement on cookies,
>   providing much greater storage capacity (10 MB per origin in Google
>   Chrome(https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/S5Q9HqDB8bh),
>   Mozilla Firefox, and Opera; 10 MB per storage area in Internet
>   Explorer) and better programmatic interfaces.

sessionStorage might be more appropriate for Web History. You'd would need to build you own Javascript to manage the data, but it would probably be faster than looking for a prebuilt option.